# Adding of a vertex in graph using adjacency-list in c++

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

This is how I've defined my graph. This is not a typical graph, it is specific to the type of problem I'm dealing with.

```
class Vertex;

class Edge
{
public:
    Vertex *org;
    Vertex *dest;
    bool dir;
};

struct Vertex{
    int id;
    vector<Edge> edges;
    int weight;
};
struct Graph{
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
};
```

I'm having problem in adding a vertex in the graph. This is how I'm doing it

```
Graph* graph1;
Vertex* first = addVertex(0);
graph1->vertices.push_back(*first);
```

The addVertex function is working properly, but if you still want to refer, here it is

```
Vertex* addVertex(int id){
    Vertex*newVertex = new Vertex;
    newVertex->id=id;
    newVertex->weight=0;
    return newVertex;
}
```

The function stops working just before graph1->vertices.push_back(*first);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graph1` itself is an unitialized pointer. So, calling it's members is causing the program to crash. Initialize it with `new` operator.

```
graph1 = new Graph();
// .......
delete graph1;
```

Or use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` to automatically manage memory.

Comment: No! Just declare `Graph graph1;`.  Only use pointers when necessary.

Comment: @japreiss In general, yes. But here it actually depends on how `graph1` grows.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the uninitialized `Graph* graph1`, there is another memory management problem in your code:

`addVertex` allocates a single `Vertex` in its own block of heap memory.  But then

```
graph1->vertices.push_back(*first);
```

*copies* `first` into the block of memory managed by `graph1`'s `std::vector`.

I guess that you are new to C++ coming from another language like Java or Python.  You should read an introductory C++ book.  Memory management in C++ has a lot of pitfalls and concepts to keep track of compared to other languages.